# Returning the last row in webservice

Tags: c#, sql, web-services

Im trying to to get all of my table records using webservice. I tried this :

```
         public class Student
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string grade;
    }
 [WebMethod]
    public Student[] getall()
    {
        Student objStd = new Student();
        Student[] stds = new Student[400];


        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = Class1.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.tblUser";
        SqlDataReader sdr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();

        for (int runs = 0; sdr.Read(); runs++)
        {
            objStd.id = Int32.Parse(sdr["Id"].ToString());
            objStd.name = sdr["name"].ToString();
            objStd.grade = sdr["grade"].ToString();
            stds[runs] = objStd;
        }
        conn.Close();
        sdr.Close();
        return stds;
    }
```

but the result of this is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <ArrayOfStudent xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 -<Student>
 <id>8</id>
 <name>hhhhh</name>
 <grade>76</grade>
 </Student>
 -<Student>
 <id>8</id>
 <name>hhhhh</name>
 <grade>76</grade>
 </Student>
 -<Student>
 <id>8</id>
 <name>hhhhh</name>
 <grade>76</grade>
 </Student>
 -<Student>
 <id>8</id>
 <name>hhhhh</name>
 <grade>76</grade>
 </Student>
  ....
```

this will return only the last record again and again, why?

what should I correct in my code?

Comment: You are changing the same object over and over again. Put `Student objStd = new Student();` in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `List` add to it and return, now you are returning only the last object.

Create the `Student` Object instance inside the For Loop

```
 List<Student> stds = new List<Student>();
 for (int runs = 0; sdr.Read(); runs++)
        {
            Student objStd = new Student();
            objStd.id = Int32.Parse(sdr["Id"].ToString());
            objStd.name = sdr["name"].ToString();
            objStd.grade = sdr["grade"].ToString();
            stds.Add(objStd);
        }
```

Comment: And return stds.ToArray() if you need an array as return value.

Comment: THANKS ALOT! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Create objStudent inside the loop so you don't keep updating the same student

```
 [WebMethod]
  public Student[] getall()
 {

    Student[] stds = new Student[400];


    SqlConnection conn;
    conn = Class1.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    newCmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.tblUser";
    SqlDataReader sdr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();

    for (int runs = 0; sdr.Read(); runs++)
    {
        Student objStd = new Student();
        objStd.id = Int32.Parse(sdr["Id"].ToString());
        objStd.name = sdr["name"].ToString();
        objStd.grade = sdr["grade"].ToString();
        stds[runs] = objStd;
    }
    conn.Close();
    sdr.Close();
    return stds;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your count of student is dynamic use list instead of array with static lenght. Also you must create student object when you read new record from Reader.

```
[WebMethod]
  public Student[] getall()
 {
    List<Student> studentList=new List<Student>();
    SqlConnection conn;
    conn = Class1.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    newCmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.tblUser";
    SqlDataReader sdr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(sdr.Read()){
        Student student= new Student();
        student.id = Int32.Parse(sdr["Id"].ToString());
        student.name = sdr["name"].ToString();
        student.grade = sdr["grade"].ToString();
        studentList.Add(student);
    }
    conn.Close();
    sdr.Close();
    return studentList.ToArray();
 }
```